# Replace number with another number of string in php

Tags: php, regex, string

How to replace number with another number like

```
$str = "www.mysite.com/campagin_id=12345";
```

i want to replace 12345 with another number 6789

so output will be

```
www.mysite.com/campagin_id=6789
```

Comment: This should be trivial.  Even if it's not, it should be fairly easy to determine from a web search.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being too lazy to put in any effort to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace('12345', '6789', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "www.mysite.com/campagin_id=12345";

preg_replace("/id=(\d+)$/", "6789", $str);
```

**output:**

```
www.mysite.com/campagin_id=6789
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/97727)

Comment: This code will replace any integer with 6789... he is asking to replace 12345 with 6789... not any number with 6789

Comment: @gurudeb, If that is the requirement , then OP could have use `str_replace()` which is pretty fast than regex.

Answer (score 0):

A regex free solution

```
<?php
$str='www.mysite.com/campagin_id=12345';
$yournum = 6789;
echo $var = explode('=',$str)[0]."=".$yournum;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
www.mysite.com/campagin_id=6789
```

[<kbd>`Demo`</kbd>](https://eval.in/97726)